# Launch .bat on a web application

Tags: java, jsf, batch-file

I'm on a JSF application, I have a `.bat` that I want to launch when clicking on a `Command` button, this script is in the webcontent directory of my project.
The code of the action is:

```
public String genererRapportTable() {
  try {
    ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) FacesContext
      .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
    String realPath = ctx.getRealPath("/");
    String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "start", realPath + "Tools\\cmd.bat" };
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
}
```

The path is correctly constructed but the script is not launched!

The debugging screen:

[image]

This what I get for output :

[image]

So the path is correct but the script is not launched. When I put the `.bat` on `c:\Tools` and I use this path `"C:\\Tools\\cmd.bat"` it works.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post the contents of the batch file?
I noticed that the actual path is used as the title for the new command prompt window. This is typical behavior of misuse of the `start` command (first argument is not the path to executable but the `title` for the new window. Don't ask me, I don't know why...)
Do you use `start` in the batch file?

Comment: java -Xmx512m -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t orathin -db nrefurg -host colline2 -port 1533 -s GA_ADM -u ga_adm  -p ga_adm -o  DOC -dp  ojdbc-14.jar -i DOC -gv "Graphviz_2.28" -hq

Comment: Just as @jeb commented, you need to add the title parameter (first parameter). Check out `start /?` in a command prompt and verify the syntax.

Comment: It is possible that you don't escape the spaces in the server path, while your test path doesn't have spaces and doesn't need escaping. This explains why the test works while the server path doesn't.

Comment: Yes it's the space, how can I escape it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use *start* to run your batch, you need to put a quoted title as first parameter, as your path contains spaces and will also be quoted.
The start command used the first quoted parameter always as title.

```
start "myTitle" cmd.exe /c myBat.bat
```

Something like this should work
`String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "\"myTitle\" \""+realPath + "Tools\\cmd.bat\""` };

You should also rename cmd.bat to a better name, so it can't collide with cmd.exe.

Comment: But it runs correctly when using : 
String[] command = { "cmd.exe", "/C", "start", "C:\\Tools\\cmd.bat" };
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
This id cmd.bat exist on c:\Tools\
The problem is only when I try this on the server directory!

Comment: I suppose that's because `C:\Tools\cmd.bat` doesn't contain spaces

Comment: Yes it's the space, how can I escape it?

Comment: Don't escape it, just be sure that it's be quoted and add a quoted title to the `start` command